# How to add line(s) after a specific line in a text file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to turn a text that looks like:

```
1 | 2 | 3
a | b | c
one | two
```

..to something like:

```
1 | 2 | 3
1
2
3
a | b | c
a
b
c
one | two
one
two
```

I'm writing a WPF application and I tried the code below (not working)

```cs
string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
string[] textLines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int l = textLines.Length;
for (int i = l; i < 1; i--)
{
    string[] questions = textLines[i].Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int n = questions.Length;
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
        textLines[i] = textLines[i] + "\n" + questions[y].Trim();
}
txtEditor.Text = string.Join("\n", textLines);
```

Comment: I am not sure, but the data in your file looks like some variation of the CSV format. If true, i would suggest to use a CSV parser such as _CsvHelper_ that can correctly read and decode various flavours of CSV. Based on the size and complexity of the actual, real content of those files your program might need to process, using a fullgrown CSV parser might also be a little overkill. Thus, take my suggestion any way you like or dislike ;-)

Comment: You're right, it's a CSV file but since there's only one column it just looks like a regular text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in your outer for loop:

1. You should start from `textLines.Length - 1` (which is the last element), not `textLines.Length`.
2. The condition is also incorrect. You should use `i >= 0` instead of `i < 1`

This should work:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
string[] textLines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int l = textLines.Length - 1;
for (int i = l; i >= 0; i--)
{
    string[] questions = textLines[i].Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int n = questions.Length;
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
        textLines[i] = textLines[i] + "\n" + questions[y].Trim();
}
txtEditor.Text = string.Join("\n", textLines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the lines, followed by parsing the items pipeline-separated.

- Don't use `\n`. Use `Environment.NewLine` instead.
- Use a `StringBuilder` to build a string, rather than concatenating strings.

code

```
static string Transform(string input)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var lines = input.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(line);
        var items = line.Split('|');
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(item.Trim());
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}

string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
txtEditor.Text = Transform(text);
```